# lex voice chatbot ssml response to amazon connect

Tags: amazon-lex, amazon-connect

SSML response from lex to contact flows in connect is not working

Text response from lex to connect is working and text to speech is generated
but when i send the response as SSML from Lex call gets disconnected
SSML is not converting into speech

```
<speak>Thank you for calling our customer support center.
<break time="2s"/> To route your call propertly
<break time="100ms"/>please listen to your menu options
</speak>
```

Connect should convert the ssml response from lex to speech
i have selected the location as US East N.Virgnia as this service is available

Comment: Hi. Please share the full format of the Lex response sent to Connect, or at least how you are forming the response, not just the speechOutput. The issue may be there, thanks.

Comment: @JayA.Little for sample i added the below content in Lex
<speak>
    I already told you I 
    <emphasis level="strong">really like</emphasis> 
    that person.
</speak>

I placed the content in MESSAGE tab in RESPONSE section it was converting as  below
<speak> I already told you I <emphasis level=&quot;strong&quot;>really like</emphasis> that person.</speak>

if i place in custom pay load i was not getting any response .

Comment: Message is correct for returning an SSML string. But how are you returning that string to Lex? Are you using a Lambda Function? If so, is it Python or Javascript? Please edit the main question to add those details and show the code. Or are you just trying to do this through the Lex developer console?